# Selecting individual XML node with condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I have a XML structure like

```
<root>
 <row>
  <value>1</value>
</row>
<row>
 <value>2</value>
</row>
</root>
```

I want to get `<row>` where `<value> = 2`. Is it possible? Any example?

To be more precise the xml structure is like this

```
<root>
 <row>
   <value>1</value>
 </row>
 <root>
   <row>
    <value>2</value>
   </row>
 </root>
</root>
```

Comment: Your updated xml structure is not well formated...and you can also use `@x.nodes('/roots/root/row') a(b)` if i assume there is a roots of all root

Comment: Updated XML. No I don't have a root of all roots

Comment: This is wired xml structure. Your first node `<row>` is directly under the root and your second `<row>` is under the `<root>` of root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
declare @x xml = '<root>
 <row>
  <value>1</value>
</row>
<row>
 <value>2</value>
</row>
</root>';

select @x.query('/root[1]/row[./value/text()="2"]');
```

Comment: Thanks Roger. Could you also please explain it. Why root[1]?

Comment: @Garima, "1" in square brackets means "first instance of element". It makes no difference in your example, but you can get somewhat better performance with bigger XML.

Comment: Thanks @Roger. My mistake I made the wrong xml. Updated my question with the right one. Could you answer now. Sorry I am a newbie in this

Comment: @Garima, it isn't a well-formed XML (both aren't, actually). Each opened node has to be closed. In the first sample, the root node has no closing tag. The same is true in the second.

Comment: @Garima, that's worse, since you have your nodes of interest on different levels. You can employ "search everywhere" mode, but it can be very costly: `select @x.query('//row[data(./value)="2"]');`